# Suse 12.1 autoyast, root password not set

Tags: suse, cobbler

I'm trying to configure autoyast to run via cobbler.
For some reason the root password is not getting set.
I've tried to use encrypted password and generating a profile from GUI autoyast and then copying the "users" section. Nothing seems to work.

This is what I have in the autoyast xml file.

```
<users config:type="list">
     <user>
       <encrypted config:type="boolean">false</encrypted>
       <user_password>password</user_password>
       <username>root</username>
     </user>
</users>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.
The problem was with the confirmation screen.
I've been testing the installation and left the confirmation screen on, so it's faster to check that all parameters are set.
I ignored the "root password not set" message and everything is working as written in autoyast xml. 
Root password is set and a regular user is created.